# VS Code on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal, compilation, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code via Anaconda Navigator to program in Python and C. It works pretty well but I can't run the active file with the integrated terminal. So far it's not that bad because I can just use it as normal text editor and use my normal shell, but I want to use the debugging features built in VS Code but I can't compile with it directly...

It just says ...: Permission denied.

Is it possible to fix this without running VS Code as root?

Thank you for your help!